# Kivy interface is quit delayed, not smooth on win10

Tags: python, anaconda, kivy

I tested the kivy code on miniconda (previously tested on anaconda, the configuration environment caused the anaconda to crash and then reinstalled miniconda). After pressing F5, the kivy interface can be generated, but it is very delayed (it reacts about 0.5 seconds after clicking,and drag,close action are quit slow too).

I think it is not normal, because the kivy interface previously generated on anaconda is very smooth.

And I found that the two generated kivy interface is not the same icon in the windows taskbar
**before is the anaconda icon (and kivy interface is very smooth),**

**now is the icon of the spyder (and kivy interface is very delay)**

Here is the test code I got from https://kivy.org/#home

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()
```

The kivy interface generated on anaconda after click F5 should be quite smooth,but it's rather delayed now

#### Conda environment

```
active environment : base
active env location : G:\Miniconda3
shell level : 1
user config file : C:\Users\38477\.condarc
populated config files :
conda version : 4.7.9
conda-build version : not installed
python version : 3.7.3.final.0
virtual packages : __cuda=9.1
base environment : G:\Miniconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
 package cache : G:\Miniconda3\pkgs
                           C:\Users\38477\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\38477\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : G:\Miniconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\38477\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\38477\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
platform : win-64
user-agent : conda/4.7.9 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
administrator : False
netrc file : None
offline mode : False
```

Comment: afaik miniconda is not an appropriate solution for this type of problem ... just use python .... or anaconda

Comment: emm,in fact,My first test was Anaconda3-4.3.1-Windows-x86_64.exe. After pressing F5, It could generate a smooth kivy interface. Later, due to configuration reasons, anaconda crashed. Then reinstall Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe, press F5 to generate a delayed kivy interface, then reinstall Anaconda3-4.3.1-Windows-x86_64.exe after uninstalling, conda install kivy error‘CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. d:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe’, and finally install Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64 .exe, it generate a delayed kivy interface after pressing F5

Comment: What's this 'pressing F5' about? It sounds like you're running Kivy from within an IDE or something? What happens if you run the code directly from the command line with that python environment?